# There are many mosquitoes come out

Tags: grammar

He walked on the drain covers and many mosquitoes flied out from the drainage.

> "Don't walk on the drain covers. There are many mosquitoes come out."
>
> "Don't walk on the drain covers. There are many mosquitoes coming
>   out."

I told him.

As the context above, should I use present tense or present continues tense?

[image]

Comment: By the way: simple past of *to fly* is *flew, not *flied*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Come out" is not the idiom I would use.  Instead I would say that many mosquitoes *live* in the drains and will *fly out* if you go near, or some similar expression like:

> Don't walk over the open drain covers.  The drains are **full of mosquitoes** and they will **swarm you** if you go near.

I use the present tense to indicate the current *condition* of the drains, but not an ongoing *action*.  I would only use the present continuous to describe something that is actually going on as I speak:

> Oh see, look.  John didn't listen to my warning and now **he's being attacked** by the swarms of mosquitoes that live in the drains.

Answer (score 1):

Mosquitoes can fly *up*, and *out of* something but the real annoyance is that they can [*bite*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154804/is-bitten-the-correct-word-choice-in-the-following-sentences).

> Don't walk **over** the drains **otherwise** you'll get **bitten by** 
>   the mosquitoes

You can use the simple future ([will](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplefuture.html)) for predictions, promises, and warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have discussed your choice of words. I will concentrate on the grammar.

It is not a matter of present or present continuous tense: this is not a tensed verb. "There is/are" already contains the main verb, and does not allow another finite verb in the clause.

If there is a verbal construction within it, it must either be an infinitive with "to":

> There are many mosquitos to come out.

(which would have the sense that they are supposed, or intended, to come out)

or a participle: the "-ing" form if it is active:

> There are many mosquitos coming out.

or the past participle if it is passive:

> There are many mosquitos seen.